# base64 Encoded String is way too long iOS

Tags: ios, encryption, encoding, base64, aes

I am encrypting images using [AESCrypt](https://github.com/Gurpartap/AESCrypt-ObjC) and converting them to NSString, so people can easily share them.. The problem is that text is too long. An Encrypted 19Kb image took minutes to copy. Is there a way I can fix this problem? Is it possible to shorten strings without losing data?

Default-569h@2x.png files base64 string with an encryption key

```
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
```

Comment: how long is your resulting base64 string? ... something around 26k or should be expected (base64 encoding raises the size by about 33-36%) ... can you specify what exactly takes so long? the encryption itself? copying the result somewhere?

Comment: regarding shortening the string... not by much ... if and only if the string ends with = or ==, you may omit those, and before decoding, pad right with = to a multiple of 4 characters

Comment: The result is very long.. I will paste an simple one here so u can see it.. 19K Default-568h.png for example is 22K which is alright however people dont wanna see that long text I believe.. Encryption takes long but the worst one is copying it to clipboard..takes too long..

Comment: Yeah.. it ends with ==.. Is it good?

Comment: just added an example output..

Comment: And what did you expect? That 19Kb image will be compressed to 100 characters, using Base64 encoding?

Comment: It is not what i am expecting.. It is what i am asking.. if you dont have any ideas, u dont have to contribute..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, no you cannot shorten the encrypted strings without losing data.  All (lossless) compression algorithms work by eliminating redundancy/patterns.  A good encryption algorithm has virtually no redundancy/patterns, so lossless compression is usually not possible.  In some cases I've even seen it *increase* the file size by adding the compression metadata to the file

Your best bet is to apply as much compression (lossy or lossless) to the image before encrypting/converting to Base-64.  I would bet that the reason the encryption/decryption takes so long is the limited resources of the mobile device.  Extensive floating point operations are hard on mobile devices, and thus they are poor platforms for encryption.

NOTE: Since the NSString class is immutable, you may want to look into the AESCrypt code to see if it is constantly appending and/or copying the string as it goes.  This would be a very inefficient way to handle it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have changed the encryption algorithm and it is working fine now.. text is still too long but at least everything is very fast.. I would have shared the code but seems like some people found it not constructive so lets keep it that way lol

Comment: FWIW I thought it was a great question :-)